# What happened to Amaravati the city of devas?

Tags: gods

In satayuga the place where devas used to live was called as Amaravati. What had happened to Amaravati now? Does this place still exist?

Comment: Nothing happened to Indra's city Amaravati now. It still exists.

Comment: But never heard something special about it and also it's not so popular.